# Parse list of dictionaries in a dataframe into separate columns

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have this data as one of the columns in the Dataframe (Pandas).  How to parse this into separate records

```
[{self=https://support.test.com/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/22846, disabled=true, id=22846, value=Data Catalog}, {self=https://support.test.com/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/22847, disabled=true, id=22847, value=Data Status Tracker}, {self=https://support.test.com/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/22848, disabled=true, id=22848, value=Enterprise Test}]
```

Please see that there is `'='` symbol instead of `':'`

Thanks much for help

Tried `yaml.load()` and tried `json` also.  But, not able to get it.  I fairly new!

Comment: That's not a list of dictionaries. Where did you get this data from? Did it come with instructions for parsing it? Is it possible to get the data in some other format, like CSV or JSON? What I'm trying to say is, writing your own parsing code can be troublesome, so it's easier to avoid the problem in the first place. You can [edit] to clarify.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask] for tips.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in this format are really unfortunate, but you can try *ad-hoc* parser using `re`:

```py
import re


def parse_string(s):
    out = []
    for group in re.findall(r"\{(.*?)\}", s):
        out.append(dict(re.findall(r"\s*([^,=]+)=([^,]+)\s*", group)))

    return out


s = """[{self=https://support.test.com/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/22846, disabled=true, id=22846, value=Data Catalog}, {self=https://support.test.com/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/22847, disabled=true, id=22847, value=Data Status Tracker}, {self=https://support.test.com/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/22848, disabled=true, id=22848, value=Enterprise Test}]"""

data = parse_string(s)
print(data)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {
        "self": "https://support.test.com/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/22846",
        "disabled": "true",
        "id": "22846",
        "value": "Data Catalog",
    },
    {
        "self": "https://support.test.com/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/22847",
        "disabled": "true",
        "id": "22847",
        "value": "Data Status Tracker",
    },
    {
        "self": "https://support.test.com/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/22848",
        "disabled": "true",
        "id": "22848",
        "value": "Enterprise Test",
    },
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Andrej Kesely.  This solved my problem.